# CPQ Quote Line Records Bundle Hierarchies with Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, cpq, quote, product, quotelineitem

While I am creating Quote Line records from the Flow.
Where products are in the form of Bundle & configured Products.
I have filled up the **required by** field on the child product Quote Line, but when I check in the Quote Line Editor, it is not showing both line records in the form of Product Hierarchies.

Can someone please suggest the required fields I am missing in Quote Line records?
Please find the Flow Screenshot
[image]

**Note:** When I have gone through with my research, it seems like it is happening due to the Number field on Quote Line Editor.
**QLI before adding Quote Line records(for Child Product Bundle)**
[image]

**QLI after adding Quote Line records(for Child Product Bundle)**
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same need as you to have a flow create a quote and the related quote lines. I also have bundles with required options associated. My issue is that I've been trying for hours to associate the bundle and the related options, but im struggling. If a bundle is selected in the screen flow, only that product is selected on the quote line editor instead of that product + the options. From what I see in your post, you did a flow that managed to do all that, especially by filling the "required_by" field. Could you please tell me more about your flow and the elements you used to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The Entire Day I was figuring out the way, and finally, I got the way and worked fine.
**The Workaround worked for me,**
On Quote Line, I updated the Child Product **SBQQ__Number__c** Field as the same that we have on its Bundle Product, **SBQQ__RequiredBy__c**.

After that, it will auto-update the Quote Line **Number** Field.
Please find the example here.

[image]

**After Auto-Update Number**
[image]

**Now, In Quote Line Editor**
[image]
Thanks, Everyone to Support.
Please share if you are having an optimal solution.